# Añadir «emojis» a una página web

Tags: javascript, html, css

He visto que sitios como `Twitter`, `Facebook`, `Bitbucket`, `Github`, `Gmail`, entre otros. Añaden `emojis` tras escribir cierto conjunto de caracteres o algunos los añaden tras publicar el contenido . Algo como:

:D - ->

Imagino que existe un escucha, programado con expresiones regulares en `JavaScript` a la espera de contenido que coincida con dicho patrón para luego remplazar por imágenes o unicode (como Font Awesome).

Me gustaría conocer que es lo que pasa para lograr eso. ¿Existe algún patrón de diseño que pueda usar?, ¿requiero tener alguna configuración especial en mi DB (`MySQL`)?.

**Nota:** Más que usar un framework (si existe) me gustaría saber como se logra.

Comment: Considero que en la [web](https://www.google.co.ve/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=emoji%20in%20javascript) hay muchos recursos para esto, con tan solo ir a github y buscar alguna librería mirarla ya esta. No soy partidario de reinventar la rueda, existiendo tantos recursos en la web. Creo que la pregunta tuviera mas valor si colocas algún punto de tu proyecto en el que te encuentres trabado.

Comment: @WilfredoP la parte final lo dice: *Más que usar un framework (si existe) me gustaría saber como se logra*. Pero si, lo mejor sería utilizar una framework robusto y que tenga mucho de esto implementado, de preferencia que sea flexible para extender los emojis o sprites a utilizar.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Por lo mismo coloque _"con tan solo ir a github y buscar alguna librería mirarla ya esta"_ te da una idea de como funciona y como poder emularla.

Comment: @WilfredoP hay personas que no pueden comprender eso tan fácilmente y necesitan ayuda para saber como podría hacerse.

Comment: Me parece que las respuestas existentes son sumamente incompletas en tanto que no utilizan Unicode. http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html En 2015 ya no hacen falta sprites 

Comment: Concretamente: https://github.com/twitter/twemoji

Comment: @astrojuanlu amigo, puedes colocar tu repuesta :)  apoyaría a la comunidad, yo aun puedo modificar la palomita en caso de ver una mejor repuesta.

Comment: @astrojuanlu creo que quienes hemos respondido nos hemos guiado por la nota al pié de la pregunta > Nota: Más que usar un framework (si existe) me gustaría saber como se logra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí hay un ejemplo de cómo hacer lo que deseas sin ninguna clase de framework, sólo Vanilla-Script:

Nota: no me dio tiempo de implementar correctamente el regex para capturar el código smile :), pero la idea general es funcional:

**Código:**

```js
window.onload = publicar;

function publicar(){
  
  var texto = document.getElementById('texto-origen').value;  
  var elemento_destino =  document.getElementById('elemento-destino');
  
  var emojis = [
    {codigo:':b',class:'emoji lengua'},
    {codigo:'xD',class:'emoji XD'},
    {codigo:':)',class:'emoji smile'}    
  ];   
  
  var result = findById( emojis, 45 );  
  
  for (i = 0; i < emojis.length; i++) { 
    
    var emoji = emojis[i];
    var image = '<div class="' + emoji.class + '"></div>'
        
    texto = replaceAll(texto,emoji.codigo,image);      
    
  }  
  
  elemento_destino.innerHTML = texto;
  
}


function findById(source, id) {
    return source.filter(function( obj ) {
        // coerce both obj.id and id to numbers 
        // for val & type comparison
        return +obj.id === +id;
    })[ 0 ];
}


function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {  
  try{
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
  }catch(ex){
    return str;
  }
}
```

```css
textarea{
  width:300px;
  margin-top:25px;
  height:50px;
}

#elemento-destino{
  font-size:2em;
  padding-top:5px;
}

.emoji{  
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
      background: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/e9/b3/13/e9b313c5bad0465c6ee1cb51b06e9e2d.jpg); 

  
}

.emoji.lengua{  
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.emoji.XD{
 
  background-position: 0px 180px;
}

.emoji.smile{  
  background-position: 60px 0px;
}
```

```html
<strong>Prueba con xD y :b</strong><br/>
<textarea id="texto-origen" class="tarea">Hola xD mundo :b</textarea>
<button onclick="publicar()">Publicar</button>
<div id="elemento-destino"></div>
```

Comment: Esta es una implementación de lo que he descrito en mi respuesta. ¡Qué interesante!

Comment: Si, claro que lo es!

Comment: Hay formas más fáciles 

Comment: @astrojuanlu Si conoces otra forma, por favor aporta. El conocimiento siempre es bueno.

Answer (score 2):

No necesitas ninguna configuración de base de datos, pues para ahorrar recursos se realiza en la PC del cliente el renderizado. Patrones de diseño en [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) no conozco, pero en otros lenguajes harías una clase estática y pública que contenga una tabla (*hash*) de todos los emoticones, en caso de usarlo extensivamente.

**Procedimiento**

Encuentras al cadena en el texto cuando la persona escribe y la remplazas por un *tag* de imágen, idealmente debes de usar un componente HTML o algo que no te limite a ingresar texto únicamente como es el caso de los `input`, la forma más fácil es agregar la propiedad `contenteditable` que te permitirá editar un fragmento del `DOM`.

Aquí tienes un pequeño ejemplo con [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)

```js
$('#editor').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {

  //alert($('#editor').html);
  var texto = $('#editor').html();
  var pos = texto.search('\\:\\)');
  if (pos != -1) {
    alert('hallado en ' + pos);
    var tam = 5;
    var inicio = texto.slice(0, pos);
    var url = "http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/smile.png";
    var fin = texto.slice(pos + tam, texto.length);
    $('#editor').html(inicio + '<img src="' + url + '" width="35">' + fin);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">escribe dos puntos paréntesis que cierra aquí=></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Lo más básico que me puedo imaginar:

- En tu página web exista una imagen con todos los [sprites](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28videojuegos%29) (en este caso, emojis) que quieres, por ejemplo cara sonriente y cara sonriente con dientes
- Utilizar JavaScript para que luego que cargue el contenido de la página (con jQuery sería via `$(document).ready()`) que evalúe el contenido de los `<p>`s o `<div>`s donde necesites que se reemplace el contenido de los símbolos como `:)` y `:D` con etiquetas `<img>` o `<span>` que representen partes de la imagen vía CSS tal como se explica [aquí](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp). Para facilitar el trabajo, podrías tener clases CSS que ya contengan como background el sprite exacto que necesitas de la imagen principal. Para identificar los `<p>`s y `<div>`s, podrías utilizar una clase CSS, de manera que reduces el análisis del texto donde se deba aplicar el cambio, y también reduces que en alguna parte del HTML generado suceda este reemplazo.